# OS X - Make returning "Nothing to be done for <filename>"

Tags: macos, bash, makefile

First of all, I would like to apologize if I'm on the wrong stackexchange network, and secondly, sorry if I'm overlooking something simple.

I was moving files from my old hard drive from an old PC when I came across several password protected ZIP Files. However, since those files were a bit old, I forgot the passwords already. I tried every password I could come up with but I still came up empty. After several google searches, I [found this tool/utility](http://aapr.sourceforge.net/how-to.html) for Mac OS X that could help me. So I go to the [downloads page](http://aapr.sourceforge.net/download.html) and download the [Mac OSX utility tool](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/aapr/aapr-0.01-macosx.tar.gz?use_mirror=osdn) and the [source code](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/aapr/aapr-0.01-source.tar.gz?use_mirror=osdn).

However, I am having problems executing the `make` command for the file. It says on the downloads page:

```
If you are using linux or another unix, you need to download the source code, uncompress it and type "make" to compile the utility.
```

So far, what I've tried is

```
$make /Users/myname/Downloads/aapr-0.01-source/Makefile
```

I have also tried the other files in the source folder but nothing worked. After that, I'm pretty much blank. I tried double clicking the `aapr` file in the utility download for Mac (which is a Unix Executable) and it opens a new terminal window displaying the commands and such. Also, doing `$aapr [options] [filename]` only shows me `-bash: aapr: command not found`. I also updated XCodes command line tools.

Sorry if I'm missing out on something very basic, I don't usually use the terminal on the OS X.

Comment: To execute a command from a specific location (that isn't in the normal `$PATH`) you need to specify a path for it. So something like `/bin/bash` or `./aapr` (where `./` means the current directory).

Comment: ^This is what helped me. I went to the directory of the aapr file and did `./appr [options] [filename]` and it was working. thanks.

Comment: Was that file in the source directory initially or did your initial `make` run actually build it correctly?

Comment: That file was in the directory initially. `make` gave me errors. Also, the program doesn't work for .zip files, it only works for .rar files. Well that's out of the scope of the question. Edit your comment in to your answer so I can mark it as correct. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running

```
cd /Users/myname/Downloads/aapr-0.01-source
make
```

A Makefile contains rules for building files from other files but it is based on paths and contents, etc. which depend on your current location. So generally you need to be in the directory of the project for it to work.

Edit (copied from my comment):

To execute a command from a specific location (that isn't in the normal $PATH) you need to specify a path for it. So something like /bin/bash or ./aapr (where ./ means the current directory).